# android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-toolbar

I have a `spinner` in `toolbar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorToolBar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextColor="#fff"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Transaction_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

    </Spinner>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and this, my `adapter` and `xml` source :

```
private class spinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, null);
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_txt1);

        item.setText(transactionType[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and `custom_spinner_item.xml`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinner_txt1"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textColor="#000"
android:gravity="right"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:padding="10dp">
```

I Changing the color of the selected spinner item by `parent.getChildAt()`

```
 TransactionTypeSpiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
```

But i get this error :

```
09-04 08:18:01.405 28605-28605/? E/Zygote: v2 09-04 08:18:01.405 28605-28605/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0 09-04 08:18:03.365 28605-28605/com.niyazdel.app.jeeb E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
    motionService = null 09-04 08:19:04.925 28605-28605/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null 09-04 08:19:04.925 28605-28605/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = null 09-04 08:19:05.065 28605-28605/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.niyazdel.app.jeeb, PID: 28605
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.niyazdel.app.jeeb.MainActivity$3.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:144)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:1166)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:1155)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1146)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1327)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:1303)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:181)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:632)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:420)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.measureChildCollapseMargins(Toolbar.java:1547)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onMeasure(Toolbar.java:1655)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:677)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:480)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3140)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2687)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1640)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1932)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1528)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7530)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

How to fix this problem?! 
Thanks.

Comment: which line does the error lead to?

Comment: Could you specify which content belongs to your file custom_spinner_item.xml?

Comment: @AngusTay ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: @MOHS3N are there multiple spinners in your Activity ?

Comment: @SudhanshuVohra No,just one!

Comment: @MOHS3N , please send LogCat message!

Comment: @Csongi77 updated issue!

Comment: Are you initializing your Spinner `Transaction_type` with `onItemSelected()` method? It seems that the `onItemSelected()` has unknown views.

Comment: @Tepits updated

Answer (score 0):

On your `onItemSelected` try to get the textView from the `View` like:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_txt1);
   tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Update:

I think it is from your `convertView`. You must check if the `convertView` is null, then if it is null, inflate your view. This should be inside your `getView()`:

```
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, null);
    } else {
        view = convertView
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_txt1);
    item.setText(transactionType[position]);
```

Comment: Its doesn't work , get this error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

The spinnerAdapter code have errors, as below:

```
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position; //here
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;//and here
        }
```

other logic is correct, and just modify above lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your `custom_spinner_item.xml` file content is direct TextView. So, you won't find a `spinner_txt1` inside the `custom_spinner_item.xml.

So, you need to use `convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, null);`
and typecast your covertView to TextView so you can set the text.

```
TextView item = (TextView) convertView;
item.setText(transactionType[position]);
```

and you can directly use the view in onItemSelected as TextView:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ((TextView) parent).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

All of this you need to do because, you have TextView as your parent view in your `custom_spinner_item.xml`

Or else just add Any ViewGroup to your `custom_spinner_item.xml` and then you will be able to use your onItemSelected code.